# Activity progress in action bar not showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, progress

I have an activity that I want to show [progress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setProgress(int)). I'm requesting the window feature before setContentView is called, yet I see no progress showing. Progress works on [0, 10000] according to the documentation. What am I missing?

The action bar appears like a normal action bar without progress, with a solid blue line underneath the title/menu

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarVisibility(true);
    setProgress(5000);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // set content view
}
```